# CSV / Dataset with hourly prices in columns for each day in the rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset / CSV with hourly prices in columns for each day in the rows. It looks something like this:

| Date | 01:00:00 | 02:00:00 | ... | 00:00:00 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2019 | 348,87 | 340,83 | ... | 343,38 |
| 02.01.2019 | ... | ... | ... | ... |

I would need the dataset to be like this:

| Date | Price |
| --- | --- |
| 01.01.2019 01:00:00 | 348,87 |
| 01.01.2019 02:00:00 | 343,38 |
| ... | ... |
| 02.01.2019 00:00:00 | ... |

And all the way to 01.01.2022.

I'm using pandas dataframes in Python. Could anyone help me with this?

RE:

df1 = pd.read_csv('Hourly_prices1.csv', delimiter = ';', index_col = ['Date'])

So basically, I want the index row to contain the price each hour on each day, going chronologically from 01.01.2019 01.00.00 all until 01.01.2022 00.00.00.

I need this to create a time series analysis, and amongst other things plot daily changes in the price of each hour of each day.

Comment: have you tried stack

Comment: please post a minimal reproducable example, e.g. code how to create (a subset of) your dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your dataset is df, Please try this:

```
hours_ls = df.columns[1:]

df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype(str)

df_new = pd.DataFrame()

for date in df['Date'].values:
  price_ls = []
  date_hr  = []
  for hour in hours_ls:
    date_hr.append(date + ' ' + str(hour))
    price_ls.append(df[df['Date']==date][hour].iloc[0])
  df_new = df_new.append(pd.DataFrame(data={'Date':date_hr,'Price':price_ls}))
```

df_new will be the formatted dataframe required